# If a node module is written in C, and I install it on Mac, do I have to reinstall it to deploy to Linux?

Tags: node.js, deployment, npm

I frequently hear from experienced node developers that checking in **node_modules** is good practice. But most developers write on Mac/Darwin x64, but deploy on Linux x64.

If a node module happens to be written in C, and I install it on OS X, wouldn't I have to rebuild it on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: **it depends on the package**

- Most packages do require reinstall, as `node gyp` the compiler does not cross compile by default - thanks @tkone.
- Some packages like `node-sass` dynamically download prebuilt binaries for the relevant platform (previously `node-sass` used to include binaries for all platforms, however this has changed recently).

Comment: node-sass specifically includes pre-built binaries. From the [readme](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#rebuilding-binaries): `Node-sass includes pre-compiled binaries for popular platforms, to add a binary for your platform follow these steps:`

Comment: Actually node-sass doesn't include the binaries in the original downloaded npm package. What it does is that its install.js will download the platform specific binary.

Comment: @jfrantzius Are you sure? Why are Windows and Linux binaries installed on the Mac in the above example?

Comment: @mikemaccana please see my other answer, it's possible that the behaviour has changed between 2014 and 2016. I tried it out yesterday :)

Comment: Ah that makes sense - you're right, I've updated the answer. Thanks @jfrantzius!

Answer (score 0):

The now current node-sass 3.4.2 doesn't include the binaries in the originally downloaded npm package (as found in the npm package cache under `~/.npm`).

What it does is that its **install.js script will download the platform specific binary** and store it under `vendor/{platform}-{arch}-{process.versions.module}.node`.  Once installed, the install.js script normally isn't invoked again by npm.

So when you check in `node_modules`, it will contain the binary only for your initial platform.

For the fun of it I moved away the downloaded binary, which should be the same as someone else checking out your `node_modules` on a different platform. When then run, node-sass is so smart to detect that the required binary doesn't exist. It exits gracefully, recommending to run `npm rebuild node-sass` (also hinting that this is usually necessary when you change the node version). This will download the binary for the current platform, and then all is fine.

However, that's totally specific to node-sass, other packages with binaries may behave entirely different.

(See [Node.js release versions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/#ref-1) for an explanation of `process.versions.modules` aka. NODE_MODULES_VERSION that determines the last number in the binary download URL. The binary name is constructed in `function getBinaryName()` in ~/.npm/node-sass/{version}/package.tgz/lib/extension.js )