# AWS and web3 deployment in lambda function error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

When i am doing upload web3 modules on AWS lambda function then getting this error.Please tell me what is reason

```
{
  "errorMessage": "/var/task/node_modules/scrypt/build/Release/scrypt.node: invalid ELF header",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/scrypt/index.js:3:20)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/scrypt.js/node.js:1:76)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You may want to add more information about your issue if you expect help. If the issue is purely related with web3js I would expect to see more people asking about it. What version of web3 do you use? What version of Node in the lambda?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bcrypt invalid elf header when running node app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809611/bcrypt-invalid-elf-header-when-running-node-app)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your scrypt module is compiled for OSX and is not compatible with the OS running the lambdas. In [serverless' git](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/308) the issue is discussed.

To bring the solutions here, a couple are given, first one is by [Kennu](https://github.com/kennu), he suggest to add a custom "install" script in the package.json:

```
"install": "[ -e node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp.node ] || docker run --rm -v $PWD:/data -w /data node:4 npm install sharp"
```

The solution I used was given by [jokeyrhyme](https://github.com/jokeyrhyme), he suggest to use the following [script](https://gist.github.com/jokeyrhyme/d57097a491aa5ecaf27532d057d72461) to be able to run npm install within a docker instance. I copy the code here:

```
'use strict'

// ideal for use with AWS Lambda and native Node.js modules

// requires Docker: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/

/*
Usage:
  node docker-npm.js install
  node docker-npm.js rebuild
*/

const childProcess = require('child_process')

const nodejsImage = 'node:4.3'
const innerWorkingDir = '/src'
const dockerArgs = [
  'run', '-i',
  '-v', `${process.cwd()}:${innerWorkingDir}`,
  '-w', innerWorkingDir,
  nodejsImage, 'npm'
]
const npmArgs = process.argv.slice(2)

const cp = childProcess.execFile(
  'docker',
  dockerArgs.concat(npmArgs),
  {},
  (err, stdout, stderr) => {}
)

cp.stderr.on('data', (data) => console.error(data))
cp.stdout.on('data', (data) => console.log(data))

cp.on('close', (code) => process.exit(code))
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having issues with running web3 > 1.0.0 and you're using SAM local to test it, consider running `sam build --use-container` prior to executing the lambda with `sam invoke local` .

This will build and install any dependencies inside of a amazon linux container instead of building it locally.