# I get bcrypt error after deployed my nodejs/expressjs app to AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, bcrypt

I am trying to make my `express.js` app works on `AWS Lambda`. The deployment (using `serverless framework` completes successfully, however the app returns a `500 internal error` when I test my requests. My logs shows me this error :

`/var/task/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header`.

I've tried to replace `bcrypt` with `bcryptjs` but the problem persists.

Also, in my `serverless.yml`, I've added the following line to force lambda to install `bcrypt` by itself, but apparently it didn't make the trick :

```
package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809611/bcrypt-invalid-elf-header-when-running-node-app) help?

Answer (score 1):

First, please include node modules. AWS won't install anything into the lambda node env besides the `aws-sdk`.

Secondly, you're seeing this error because your likely developing on a mac OS machine, so the `bycrypt` binary from your machine is ending up getting uploaded to lambda.

Please double check that when you tried `bcryptjs`, you fully removed `bcrypt` from your project dependencies.